# iOS News App like Animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uicollectionview

How can I achieve the following [animation](https://ibb.co/mZgAGF)?

https://ibb.co/mZgAGF

Consider the list of cells in `UITableView`/`UICollectionView`.When the user taps on an `UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell`, the detail page animates/opens from the selected cell and when we go back, the detail view goes inside the selected cell.

Please let me even if we've any existing libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: creating an own transition, maybe? here is a random tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll go through the tutorial, Do we have any specific tutorial/library for this?

Comment: it is a standard iOS feature which you can customise.

Comment: https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer  , try this